# how to disable the cors request while redirecting to another url

Tags: ajax, spring, cors

I have an ajax request which does a post to spring controller, where there is response.sendRedirect(externalurl) to external url.

Issue is externalurl does not support cors/jsonp.
But since it is ajax request with cors, "origin" header gets set.
Is there any way to remove the origin header and do response.sendredirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully do it using spring Redirect model and View method. 
I stopped using response.sendRedirect.

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("redirect:" + authURL);
    return model;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use response.reset() before sendRedirect.I think it will work in case external url doesn't expects something explicitly.

Comment: are you sure you don't have anything else configure which is setting these headers? for eg. some filters might be belonging to spring framework itself?

Comment: ajax request from jsp page is setting "origin" header. There is nothing on the spring side.. no filters...

Comment: what error you are getting, how did you identified that it's because of origin header?